# ASP.Net dynamic scraping not working with scrapy

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a problem with this code. trying to scrape a website

```
    def parse(self, response):
        form_data= self.validate(response)
        for day in range(28, 30):
            formdata={'TopControl1$ScriptManager1': 'Ponderation1$UpdatePanel1|Ponderation1$ImageButton1',
                '__EVENTTARGET': '',
                '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
                '__VIEWSTATE': response.xpath("//*[@id='__VIEWSTATE']/@value")[0].extract(),
                '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': response.xpath("//*[@id='__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR']/@value")[0].extract(),
                'TopControl1$TxtRecherche': '',
                'TopControl1$txtValeur': '',
                'Ponderation1$Marche': 'RBMasi',
                'Ponderation1$DateTimeControl1$TBCalendar': str(day) + '/11/2018',
                'Ponderation1$DateTimeControl2$TBCalendar': '',
                'Ponderation1$DateTimeControl3$TBCalendar': '',
                'hiddenInputToUpdateATBuffer_CommonToolkitScripts': '1',
                '__AjaxControlToolkitCalendarCssLoaded': '',


    def extract_parties(self, response):
        for i in range(0, 8):
            name=response.xpath("//span[starts-with(@id,'Ponderation1_RPTLPonderation_ctl01_LB')]/text()")[i].extract()
            name=name.replace(u'\xa0', u'')
            print(name)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
cookies = {
    'f5avrbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb': 'HGBDJPEAGIFIAHDFGPNJHAINMFBDCDBOHCFGJPCDNBAJBMBMCDIJKIPAOGEGAMMNMKODNCIDMCLHHLGADPKAGFBDJNGJHKLNBGCLGEODFONGKOCFLDCFMBFLHJBHGNMH',
    'f5_cspm': '1234',
    'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'iofa0g55jg2oglvg1d51z545',
    '__utma': '225058952.721807667.1544016642.1544016642.1544016642.1',
    '__utmc': '225058952',
    '__utmz': '225058952.1544016642.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)',
    '__utmt': '1',
    '__utmb': '225058952.1.10.1544016642',
    'TS01d86d3f': '01a50d1c3688e0ee59cfd5a55701630671258cc4cb871bb2f687b5afb59839c49b3853a3b65627f713ba9c653c850f3c5fe2e7e71d2dc135cfa34530da73c2acb150fa64999f3bec6ba67985fd4558b0e7772ee873a9640706fa3f523aa435169c7412ce3a315edd67f5796883c2b497aeb478375c',
}

headers = {
    'Origin': 'http://www.casablanca-bourse.com',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Referer': 'http://www.casablanca-bourse.com/bourseweb/indice-ponderation.aspx?Cat=22&IdLink=298',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'X-MicrosoftAjax': 'Delta=true',
    'DNT': '1',
}


data = {
  'TopControl1$ScriptManager1': 'Ponderation1$UpdatePanel1|Ponderation1$ImageButton1',
  '__EVENTTARGET': '',
  '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
  '__VIEWSTATE': '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',
  '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': 'D0762CE0',
  'TopControl1$TxtRecherche': '',
  'TopControl1$txtValeur': '',
  'Ponderation1$Marche': 'RBMasi',
  'Ponderation1$DateTimeControl1$TBCalendar': '25/12/2018',
  'Ponderation1$DateTimeControl2$TBCalendar': '',
  'Ponderation1$DateTimeControl3$TBCalendar': '',
  'hiddenInputToUpdateATBuffer_CommonToolkitScripts': '1',
  'Ponderation1$ImageButton1.x': '35',
  'Ponderation1$ImageButton1.y': '3'
}

yield FormRequest('http://www.casablanca-bourse.com/bourseweb/indice-ponderation.aspx?IdLink=298&Cat=22', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, formdata=data)
```